# ui:inputDate inline change handling not working in browser?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, ui

I have a `ui:inputDate` control in my component which I am supplying a callback to the `change` event.

```
<ui:inputDate aura:id="some-id"\
              label="Some Label"
              value="{!v.theValue}"
              displayDatePicker="true"
              change="{!c.doSomething}"/>
```

When I select a date, the callback function does not fire when in a standard web browser.  However, it works are expected on a mobile device inside SF1.

Have tested in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Even I have noticed the same behavior.

Following are my findings after looking deeper into the behavior of **ui:inputDate**

1. If user type something using keyboard then **change** event is fired
2. If user changes the date using the Calendar UI then **change** event is not getting fired

**Work Around -** So what you can do here is instead of using **change** event you should use **blur** event which will work as per expectation.

Hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same behavior for both inputDate and inputDateTime.  But "change" seems to work with inputText.  Haven't tested all the various inputs, but might be a bug in some of the ui:input components?

I found this post where somebody said to use select instead of change, and I tested it and it does seem to work:

[ui:inputDate change event not firing](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/137374/uiinputdate-change-event-not-firing)

There are some other answers in that thread that might be more appropriate, but using select instead of change might be an easy workaround since you just have to change an attribute name.

Hope this info helps!